# Data Not Inserted To The Server Due to BackgroundFallback initVivoBgFallback

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I am trying to insert data into mysql through my android phone but it's not inserted or not throw any error at runtime. I have Debug the code and found Error as under.

here is my code

My JavaFile

```
 package com.example.digitalrukhivalmikisamaj;
 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Button;

 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.Map;

 import com.android.volley.Request;
 import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
 import com.android.volley.Response;
 import com.android.volley.RetryPolicy;
 import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
 import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
 import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;



 public class applicationform extends AppCompatActivity {

 // Creating EditText.
 EditText FirstName, LastName ;

 // Creating button;
 Button InsertButton;

 // Creating Volley RequestQueue.
 RequestQueue requestQueue;

 // Create string variable to hold the EditText Value.
 String FirstNameHolder, LastNameHolder;

 // Creating Progress dialog.
 ProgressDialog progressDialog;

 // Storing server url into String variable.
 String HttpUrl = "https://192.168.1.100/dbeng/get_data1.php";

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_applicationform);


    // Assigning ID's to EditText.
    FirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    LastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fname);

    // Assigning ID's to Button.
    InsertButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    // Creating Volley newRequestQueue .
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationform.this);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(applicationform.this);

    // Adding click listener to button.
    InsertButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // Showing progress dialog at user registration time.
   progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait, We are Inserting Your Data on 
   Server");
            progressDialog.show();

            // Calling method to get value from EditText.
            GetValueFromEditText();



            // Creating string request with post method.
            StringRequest stringRequest = new 
 StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, HttpUrl,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String ServerResponse) {

          // Hiding the progress dialog after all task complete.
                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                            // Showing response message coming from server.
                            Toast.makeText(applicationform.this, 
 ServerResponse, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) 
 {

                // Hiding the progress dialog after all task complete.
                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                    // Showing error message if something goes wrong.
                            Toast.makeText(applicationform.this, 
 volleyError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                    // Creating Map String Params.
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String> ();

                    // Adding All values to Params.
                    params.put("first_name", FirstNameHolder);
                    params.put("last_name", LastNameHolder);

                    return params;
                }

            };


            // Creating RequestQueue.
            RequestQueue requestQueue = 
 Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationform.this);

            // Adding the StringRequest object into requestQueue.
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

        }
    });



}

// Creating method to get value from EditText.
public void GetValueFromEditText(){

    FirstNameHolder = FirstName.getText().toString().trim();
    LastNameHolder = LastName.getText().toString().trim();

   }



 }
```

My Gradle File

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
 compileSdkVersion 29
 buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.digitalrukhivalmikisamaj"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}

 dependencies {

 implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
 implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
 androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
 androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

 implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:+'

 implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:+'

 implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:+'

 implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'

 android{
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
 }


 android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
  }

 }
```

DatabaseConfig File

```
 <?php

 //Define your host here.
 $HostName = "localhost";

 //Define your database username here.
 $HostUser = "root";

 //Define your database password here.
 $HostPass = "";

 //Define your database name here.
 $DatabaseName = "rukhivalmiki";

 ?>
```

My GetData PHP File

```
 <?php

 include 'DatabaseConfig.php' ;

 $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $fname = $_POST['fname'];

 $Sql_Query = "insert into appform (name,fname) values ('$name','$fname')";

 if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query)){

 echo 'Data Submit Successfully';

 }
 else{

 echo 'Try Again';

 }
 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

Debug Consol Error is here:

```
 11/25 13:57:40: Launching 'app' on vivo vivo 1806.
 $ adb shell am start -n
enter code here "com.example.digitalrukhivalmikisamaj/com.example.digitalrukhivalmikisamaj.MainA 
 ctivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 
 -D Waiting for application to come online: 
 com.example.digitalrukhivalmikisamaj | 
 com.example.digitalrukhivalmikisamaj.test
 Waiting for application to come online: 
 com.example.digitalrukhivalmikisamaj | 
 com.example.digitalrukhivalmikisamaj.test
 Connecting to com.example.digitalrukhivalmikisamaj
 Waiting for application to start debug server
 Waiting for application to come online: 
 com.example.digitalrukhivalmikisamaj | 
 com.example.digitalrukhivalmikisamaj.test
 Connecting to com.example.digitalrukhivalmikisamaj
 Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior 
 can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings 
 page.
 I/System.out: Debugger has connected
 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
 Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
 I/chatty: uid=10193(com.example.digitalrukhivalmikisamaj) identical 1 line
 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
 I/System.out: debugger has settled (1413)
 I/FtBuild: getRomVersion mRomVer=9.0
 W/khivalmikisama: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;- 
 >computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z 
 (light greylist, reflection)
 W/khivalmikisama: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;- 
  >makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
 D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels fEnTdshp 0 fISOSpeedRatings -1!
 I/chatty: uid=10193(com.example.digitalrukhivalmikisamaj) identical 1 line
 D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels fEnTdshp 0 fISOSpeedRatings -1!
 D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels fEnTdshp 0 fISOSpeedRatings -1!
 D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels fEnTdshp 0 fISOSpeedRatings -1!
 D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels fEnTdshp 0 fISOSpeedRatings -1!
 D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels fEnTdshp 0 fISOSpeedRatings -1!
 D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels fEnTdshp 0 fISOSpeedRatings -1!
 D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels + (2004, 2004)
 SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels fEnTdshp 0 fISOSpeedRatings -1!
 D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels -
 D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels fEnTdshp 0 fISOSpeedRatings -1!
 I/chatty: uid=10193(com.example.digitalrukhivalmikisamaj) identical 1 line
 D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels fEnTdshp 0 fISOSpeedRatings -1!
 D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
 I/SurfaceFactory: [static] sSurfaceFactory = 
 com.mediatek.view.impl.SurfaceFactoryImpl@4f88b56
 D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]: hardware acceleration = true , 
 fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = 
 false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
 V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = 
 android.view.ViewRootImpl@a0fd3ad, this = DecorView@a06e2[MainActivity]
 V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = 
 android.view.ViewRootImpl@a0fd3ad, this = DecorView@a06e2[MainActivity]
 D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]: onDisplayChange oldDisplayState=1 
 newDisplayState=2
 D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]: onDisplayChange oldDisplayState=2 
 newDisplayState=2
 V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = 
 android.view.ViewRootImpl@a0fd3ad, this = DecorView@a06e2[MainActivity]
 D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x78c0a4c000)
 I/ConfigStore: 
 android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorD 
 isplay retrieved: 0
 I/ConfigStore: 
 android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay 
 retrieved: 0
 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
 D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
 E/OpenGLRenderer: Device claims wide gamut support, cannot find matching 
 config, error = EGL_SUCCESS
 D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x78c0a4c000,api=1)
 D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, 
 EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
 D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x78c0a4c000,api=1)
 D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x78c0a4c000,api=1)
 D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, 
 EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
 E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
 W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token 
 android.os.BinderProxy@e3fd48c
 D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels fEnTdshp 0 fISOSpeedRatings -1!
 I/khivalmikisama: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void 
 android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, 
 android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
 V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = null, this 
  = DecorView@87e7050[]
 D/ViewRootImpl[applicationform]: hardware acceleration = true , 
 fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = 
  false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
 V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = 
 android.view.ViewRootImpl@9f4506f, this = 
 DecorView@87e7050[applicationform]
 D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x78c09ce000)
 D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x78c09ce000,api=1)
 D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, 
 EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
 D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x78c0a4c000,api=1)
 V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = 
 android.view.ViewRootImpl@a0fd3ad, this = DecorView@a06e2[MainActivity]
 I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 8572 bytes, containing 1 
 windows, 26 views
 E/BackgroundFallback: initVivoBgFallback 
 callstackcom.android.internal.policy.DecorView.<init>:379 
 com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateDecor:2439 
 com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor:2817 
 com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView:451 
 com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent:292 
 android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate:444 
 android.app.ProgressDialog.onCreate:272 
 android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate:442 android.app.Dialog.show:337 
 com.example.digitalrukhivalmikisamaj.applicationform$1.onClick:68 
 D/ViewRootImpl[applicationform]: hardware acceleration = true , 
 fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = 
 false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
 I/khivalmikisama: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
 W/Thread-8: type=1400 audit(0.0:42798): avc: denied { read } for 
 name="u:object_r:mtk_em_tel_log_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=13085 
 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c193,c256,c512,c768 
 tcontext=u:object_r:mtk_em_tel_log_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
 E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.log.tel_dbg"
 D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using 
 platform default
 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek- 
  cta.jar
 I/System.out: e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaHttp
 D/Linux: [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.example.digitalrukhivalmikisamaj 
 :443 
 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek- 
  cta.jar
 I/System.out: e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaHttp
 D/Linux: [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.example.digitalrukhivalmikisamaj 
 :443 
 I/Choreographer: Skipped 2904 frames!  The application may be doing too 
 much work on its main thread.
 I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=48842ms; Flags=1, 
 IntendedVsync=3208301042060, Vsync=3256887288164, 
 OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, 
 HandleInputStart=3256901809884, AnimationStart=3256902370731, 
 PerformTraversalsStart=3256911987884, DrawStart=3257135068115, 
 SyncQueued=3257137194269, SyncStart=3257137387807, 
 IssueDrawCommandsStart=3257137573115, SwapBuffers=3257141423500, 
 FrameCompleted=3257143611269, DequeueBufferDuration=591000, 
 QueueBufferDuration=925000, 
 D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]: onDisplayChange oldDisplayState=2 
 newDisplayState=1
 D/ViewRootImpl[applicationform]: onDisplayChange oldDisplayState=2 
 newDisplayState=1
 D/ViewRootImpl[applicationform]: onDisplayChange oldDisplayState=2 
 newDisplayState=1
 V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = 
 android.view.ViewRootImpl@9f4506f, this = 
 DecorView@87e7050[applicationform]
 D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x78c09ce000,api=1)
 D/View: [Warning] assignParent to null: this = 
 DecorView@95aa560[applicationform]
 V/Typeface: CurFontPath: /system/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
 D/Typeface: switch to android orgin ttf
 D/ViewRootImpl[Toast]: hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = 
 false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, 
 sSystemRendererDisabled = false
 D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x78c09ce000)
 D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x78c09ce000,api=1)
 D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, 
 EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
 D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x78c09ce000,api=1)
 D/View: [Warning] assignParent to null: this = 
 android.widget.LinearLayout{7fd96ea V.E...... ......ID 0,0-610,88}
 D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]: onDisplayChange oldDisplayState=1 
 newDisplayState=2
 D/ViewRootImpl[applicationform]: onDisplayChange oldDisplayState=1 
 newDisplayState=2
 V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = 
 android.view.ViewRootImpl@9f4506f, this = 
 DecorView@87e7050[applicationform]
 D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x78c09ce000)
 D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x78c09ce000,api=1)
 D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, 
 EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
 Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 
 'socket'
```

I have tested PHP File its OK. Dont know whats wrong?.

Comment: What is the actual response body your app receives from your PHP file?

Comment: @rickdenhaan  there are no response received from app to php file but I have tested PHP File on Browser its works perfectly

Comment: No response at all? You mean your `httpEntity` is `null` or `httpEntity.getContent()` is empty?

Comment: @rickdenhaan What the solution?.

Comment: Well, first we need to find out what the problem is. Is your request even executing? Is it reaching the correct server? Does it receive "Try Again" or a 500 error? You're not checking for any of these things in your code, the `catch`es do nothing except pretend everything is fine so maybe you can add some logging there to see if they're catching an error or you can try using the debugger to step through your code to find out where it's going wrong.

Comment: @rickdenhaan No Not any messages received like "Data Submit Successfully" Or "Try Again" or a 500 error